# Error localhost in wamp

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp

I've installed wamp server.Then cpoied wordpress folder in www directory.Then when I tried to access this folder from localhost I got this error.
After  entering Localhost in browser, My project portion showing wordpress folder is showing.

[image]

But when I click on wordpress folder this error pops out.

This site cant be reached right now.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project Links do not work on Wamp Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server)

Comment: Try to add folder to *www* let's name it *test* and add **index.php** file to this folder and add test code like `<h1>Test</h1>`
and try again to access the file by **http://localhost/test**

if the page open correct, so may be there is error in wordpress configuration